# jQuery Validation in RoR

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-validate

```
map.check_email "users/check_email", :controller => "users", :action => "check_email"
map.resources :users
```

In the tutorial it tells me to add this to my routes.rb
but i get the error

```
undefined local variable or method `map' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x5f8f308>
```

I'm using rails 3.0.9, how do i fix this?

Comment: the title of your question is a little misleading, this has to do with routing, not with jquery validation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in rails 3 you dont't use anymore map.resources

just use `resources :users` instead

refer to this guide for routing in Rails 3:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

if you want a specific route name for check_mail, like

www.myapp.com/check_mail you could do this in your routes:

```
  match 'check_mail' => "users#check_mail"
```

Comment: you could do   get "users/check_mail" but if you have users as a resource and an controller action called check_mail then you don't need to specify this in your routes, the controller will handle that action for you.